# Create new server in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I start SQL Server 2008 R2, I connect to the database server of (local).  I want to create another database server at (local)/mypath.

However, I don't see where this can be done.  Can I run multiple database servers on one machine?

Comment: There is an option in the installer to modify the installation - Add Instance. It's more of a http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/ question, though...

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a new instance, not a new database; Either way, it's not a programming question, and may be better answered on a sister site such as http://serverfault.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If all you are trying to do is create a new database, each instance can hold several databases (up to several thousand per instance).

Answer (score 7):

you have to run the installer again and install a named instance